# Glyph doesn't show hollow space

Tags: font-forge

I drew the inside line of my O before the outside line. Now the O just looks like a circle, the inner part of the O isn't empty. How do I get it empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the toolbar, go to Element > Correct Direction. That fixes it.